# ComboBox Data Type Issue

Tags: ms-access

I have a group of forms that are interlinked to one another in MS Access. Their primary functions as a group are for me to store codes I use for querying for future references or if I ever happen to get a similar request. I have an `Insert, Search and Update form`. The `Insert form has three fields Keywords[text box]` (which is where I input the words to reference the codes), Source [combo box] (the database where the data is stored), and Code [text box] (which is where I put the actual code). All the data from the Insert forms gets put on a main table that stores all my codes (KWTable)

`The Search form has 1 text box field`, where I type in the key word to search and it brings up any code with that particular string in the keyword field.

`The Update form is giving me problems` however. The purpose of it is to be able to pull up any code and make modifications if need be. There are two primary fields `Keywords [combobox]` (has the list of all the keyword lists for the codes) and `Code [text box]` (once a keyword string is chosen it populates with the corresponding code). The problem is only 255 characters of the code ever appears, which obviously means its an NVARCHAR(255) data type, in the main table that houses evertyhing the fields are the following data types Keyword = Text, Source = Text, Code = Memo. In the Update form Code Field I have the source as =[Combo13].Column to match the code with the keywords, I am thinking that the code is picking up on the Keywords Data Type (text) and bringing it over to the code box. I need for this "Code" box to be a Memo data type. I cannot change the KW Data type in the table to Memo because that is also my Primary Key, which it will no longer be if it is Memo type.

Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Not enough information to provide an answer. Is the `Code` storing correctly in the database? In that case, research truncation of memo fields. If not, show us your code.

Comment: It is storing fine in the database, the issue is with the Update form. It is reading the code as a NVARCHAR(255) data type and not displaying the full codes.

Comment: @user2119980 : better show the code ...........

Answer (score 0):

" *I cannot change the KW Data type in the table to Memo because that is also my Primary Key, which it will no longer be if it is Memo type.* "

I would recommend that you add an arbitrary `AutoNumber` to be the primary key. Then, for your code field, make it a `Memo` type and for the `Indexed` property, change it to `Yes (No Duplicates)`

For databases, it's generally better to have a number as a primary key and just add a Unique Key to the text value that you would be considering as a PK.